# Turn areas of an image in to separate links.

Tags: html

I did this a while back but can't remember what it's called. I'd like to define three sections of an image and have them link to separate websites. what is this called and how do I do it? thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

That is called an **image map**, although they are less common now.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.6

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `<map>` tag:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
   <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
   <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
   <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```